# In Django Celery how can I tell if a task has been executed asynchronously

Tags: python, django, celery

how can I tell from within a celery task, if the task has been called from just the apply method, rather then the apply_async ( or delay ).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can look at the `is_eager` or `called_directly` attributes of `self.request` within the task (the [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html) currently isn't very clear on the difference):

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def task_with_context(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print self.request.is_eager, self.request.called_directly
```

Comment: is_Eager is returning true if it's called synchronously, but I yet have no idea what called_directly does.

Comment: called_directly is when you call the task directly: `task_with_context(arg1, arg2)` (i.e. `task.__call__`).   CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER is kind of an anti pattern for unittests since you are only testing the eager part of the celery code, so the best recommendation is to use mocks when testing and only enable always_eager as a backup to make sure tasks that you did not mock by mistake are not trying to connect to the broker.

Comment: `task.request.called_directly` evaluated as I expected: True when called synchronously and executed locally, and False when called asynchronously and executed by a worker. For some reason `task.request.is_eager` evaluated as False for me regardless.

Comment: @asksol why is `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` an anti-pattern? Any proof link for "best recommendation"?